# Get the paragraph matching to a query when using Google in Python

Tags: python, google-search

I am using the `google` package to search in python as follows:

```
from google import google 
query = 'The query'
results = google.search(query)
```

How can I get the paragraph that matches to the query in the returned links? It seems `results[i].description` stores the description that is displayed by Google search engine, but I want the whole paragraph in the document.

Comment: if you want the whole paragraph in a web document better to use beautifulsoup library. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @Chathuranga Thanks, but is it an easy way to find that paragraph in the html file?

Comment: Whats the pip package you are using? https://pypi.org/project/google/ this one?

Comment: @Chathuranga I think it is this one: https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API